Candidates filing multiple nominations for the same constituency in Indian elections
As per the section 33(6) of The Representation of The People Act, 1951

Nothing in this section shall prevent any candidate from being nominated by more than one nomination paper:
Provided that not more than four nomination papers shall be presented by or on behalf of any candidate or accepted by the returning officer for election in the same constituency.

How do these nominations differ from each other which save them from being rejected?

I’m voting to close this question because that would belong to politics

@Trish This question relates to the differentiating aspects of candidate nominations under the RoPA 1951. This law deals with elections in India. Isn't it more about the law than the underlying politics?

I don't understand the question.  Where does it say that the four nomination papers need to be different? And where does it say the criteria for rejection?

Still, it might get better answers in Politics SE (which has a law tag for just this kind of election law-related question). Perhaps if it's closed here the moderators might migrate it there.
